# Codeforces 1352A - Sum of Round Numbers Solution?

Tags: c++17

A positive (strictly greater than zero) integer is called round if it is of the form d00...0. In other words, a positive integer is round if all its digits except the leftmost (most significant) are equal to zero. In particular, all numbers from 1
to 9
(inclusive) are round.

For example, the following numbers are round: 4000
, 1
, 9
, 800
, 90
. The following numbers are not round: 110
, 707
, 222
, 1001
.

You are given a positive integer n
(1≤n≤104
). Represent the number n
as a sum of round numbers using the minimum number of summands (addends). In other words, you need to represent the given number n
as a sum of the least number of terms, each of which is a round number.

Input
The first line contains an integer t
(1≤t≤104
) — the number of test cases in the input. Then t
test cases follow.

Each test case is a line containing an integer n
(1≤n≤104
).

Output
Print t
answers to the test cases. Each answer must begin with an integer k
— the minimum number of summands. Next, k
terms must follow, each of which is a round number, and their sum is n
. The terms can be printed in any order. If there are several answers, print any of them.

My Solution :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>

#define in(x) cin>>x
#define out(x) cout<<x
#define vi vector<int>
#define pb push_back
#define testCase \
    int t; \
    cin>>t; \
    while(t--)

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    testCase{
        vi v{1000,100,10, 1};
        vi ans;
        int n; in(n);
        for(int i: v){
            if(n>=i){
                if(n>0 && n<=i)  ans.pb(n);
                else ans.pb(n-(n%i));
                n%=i;
            }
        }
        out(ans.size()<<endl);
        for(int i: ans){
            out(i<<" ");
        }
        out(endl);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Just submit my solution that it is convenient for other programmers.